# need to add IP access list to ACL for Cisco Switch Access

Tags: networking, cisco, wide-area-network

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I could not access my Cisco 3750 switch from the data center IP earlier today. It's in extended IP list but not standard. I can access from both IPs in standard, not sure why extended didn't work.

```
Cisco3750#show access-lists
Standard IP access list 1
    10 permit 66.221.xxx.xxx (8 matches)
    20 permit 66.221.xxx.xxx (86 matches)
Extended IP access list 115
    10 permit tcp host 174.128.xxx.xxx host 0.0.0.0 eq 22
Extended IP access list Manage-SSH
    10 permit tcp host 66.221.xxx.xxx host 0.0.0.0 eq 22
    20 permit tcp host 174.128.xxx.xxx host 0.0.0.0 eq 22
```

I would appreciate help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you haven't applied the ACL to the vty lines.

Try something like this:

```
line vty 0 15
access-class Manage-SSH in
length 0
transport input ssh
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @pete but I ran that and show access-lists still shows the same results.

Comment: I doubted myself there for a second, but I think if you used a standard ACL on the VTY ports it would achieve the same desired results: restricted SSH access to a select few hosts.